# Regex string in IOS application

Tags: c#, regex, xamarin

I am trying to convert string which i take form `NSDictionary` as a dictionary and then I have to via method :

```
string NSDictionaryConverter(string name)
        {
            foreach (var a in str)
            {
                if (a.Key.Description.Equals(name))
                {
                    result = a.Value.ToString();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(str.Keys);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Take what ever i need.

Why do I use dictionary ? These dictionary contains information for everything which conatain annotation from the map.

The Key `FormattedAddressLines` contatins for example :

```
FormattedAddressLines =     (
        "ZIP City Name",
        Country
    );
```

The value which with I have problems is address, because it contains a lot of details. I need all them displayed nicely on the screen.

Namely, I need to remove `"`, `(`, `)` chars and line breaks with whitespace before punctuation.

After regex it looks still messy :

[image]

```
string address = NSDictionaryConverter("FormattedAddressLines");
                string city = NSDictionaryConverter("City");
                string zip = NSDictionaryConverter("ZIP");
                string country = NSDictionaryConverter("Country");
                address = Regex.Replace(address, @"([()""])+", "");
                fullAddress = address + ", " + city + ", " + zip + ", " + country;
                addressLabel.Text = fullAddress;
```

How could i do this to looks like :

Full Address value, - new line
XXX, - new line
XXX, - new Line 
... - new line
N value - new line

Comment: Your question is very unclear as you have not stated the specs. What does your code have to do? Remove line breaks before punctuation? Use `Regex.Replace(address, @"(?:\r?\n|\r)+([\p{Zs}\t]*\p{P})", "$1")`.

Comment: Need to remove " char, ( char, ) char, line breaks before punctuation - to looks nice without unnecessary chars and line breaks / white lines

Comment: Does it work any better?

Comment: Waiting for compilation, had some problems with connection between mac -,-, great platform !

Comment: I see, that is why I added `\r` as a line break char to the regex, as on Mac,  the default line break style is CR.

Comment: How would look the second argument ? To avoide the invalid expression term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131325/discussion-between-wiktor-stribizew-and-derpyunknown).

Comment: The replacement pattern is the same, an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to remove specific special characters and whitespace before punctuation.

You need to add a `\s*(?:\r?\n|\r)\s*(?=\p{P})` alternative to your regex:

```
Regex.Replace(address, @"[()""]+|\s*(?:\r?\n|\r)+\s*(?=\p{P})", "")
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `\s*` matches 0+ whitespaces,  `(?:\r?\n|\r)+` matches 1 or more line breaks and `\s*(?=\p{P})` matches 0+ whitespaces that are followed with a punctuation symbol. It might be necessary to replace `\p{P}` with `[\p{P}\p{S}]` if you also want to include symbols.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%28%29%22%5d%2b%7c%5cs*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%7c%5cr%29%2b%5cs*%28%3f%3d%5cp%7bP%7d%29&i=%28ul.%29+%22Marsza%c5%82kowska+75%22%09%0d%0a++%2c+Warszawa&r=):

[image]